# Are there any plans to support Swift 4 with Material?

Tags: swift4, cosmicmind

I'm using Material framework under Swift 3.1 (Xcode 8.x), but now under Swift 4 (Xcode 9) it is not able to compile... are there any plans to convert to Swift 4?

Comment: This belongs to the GitHub Issues of Material.

Comment: You don't need it in Swift 4. You can use Swift 3.2 frameworks in Xcode 9 while your code is in Swift 4. This is not an issue.

Comment: @Moritz that was a good hint thx!
BTW: You're right.. i expect a Yes  or no. So i can decide if i do it by myself or i can wait for it ;)

Comment: What is "Material"? Do you mean "a material framework" (material as in [Material Design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Material_Design))?

Comment: @Peter Mortensen: It's a framework of cosmicmind for iOS

Answer (score 3):

As of [Material 2.10.3](https://github.com/CosmicMind/Material/releases/tag/2.10.3) - The [master](https://github.com/CosmicMind/Material/tree/master) branch supports Swift 4 :) All the best!

Comment: While this link may answer the question... just kidding, this *is* the perfect answer for this question.